# Is this Where condition in Linq-to-sql join correct?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, inner-join, where-clause

I have the following Iqueryable method to show details of a singl material,

```
public IQueryable<Materials> GetMaterial(int id)
{
    return from m in db.Materials
           join Mt in db.MeasurementTypes on m.MeasurementTypeId equals Mt.Id
           where m.Mat_id equals id
            select new Materials()
            {
              Id = Convert.ToInt64(m.Mat_id),
              Mat_Name = m.Mat_Name,
              Mes_Name = Mt.Name,
            };
}
```

Any suggestion....

Comment: Well it looks reasonably okay to me (although it would help if you'd be consistent in your casing) - my only immediate concern would be the Convert.ToInt64... why is your Materials class using a different ID type? Why are *you* concerned? Does it not work? If not, in what *way* doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause should be a boolean expression, like this:

```
where m.Mat_id == id
```

You use the keyword `equals` for joins, but a `where` clause should use a boolean expression, think of it this way: whatever is in `where something` it should work as if it were in a `if(something)`.